# PDO, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?
I am new to PDO and need to learn how to insert using bindValue but nothing is been added to my database when I hit submit. Not even an error is shown.

Can anyone give an example.
Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head><title>PDO INSERT TEST</title>
<meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<form action="PDO_test1.php" method="POST">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="userName" id="Name"/></p>
<p>Last: <input type="text" name="userLast" id="Last"/></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
    # basic pdo connection (with added option for error handling)
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        require_once 'includes/PDO_connect.php';
        try {
            $dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname";
            $dbc = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
            //You can echo out connected to db message
            $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $query = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO `PdoTest1` (userName,userLast,reqistration_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            # If we leave out the third parameters, it is set to
            # PDO::PARAM_STRING by default
            $query->bindValue(':userName', '%' . $_POST['userName'] . '%');
            $query->bindValue(':userLast', '%' . $_POST['userLast'] . '%');
            $dbc = null;
        }

        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        //echo "<p>Data submitted successfully</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: my syntax is not inserting anything in the database.. I don't even know if it looks like it makes any sense. I don't get any errors..

Comment: You don't show error gived. But note you don't set third parameter of the query and you don't exeucte the query `$query->execute()`.

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting errors from using the wrong placeholders. `?` and `:var` don't mix. and why the `'%'`? that is LIKE syntax.

Comment: RTM on this http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: how can I work with the registration date for the third parameter.. ? need a little guidance guys pls!.

Comment: I've given you a link for it, you need to read it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you so much! will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the examples given in the manual:

http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

They are going to help you a lot. Reading them you could change your code like this:

```
$query = $dbc->prepare( "INSERT INTO `PdoTest1` (userName,userLast,reqistration_date) 
VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
# If we leave out the third parameters, it is set to
# PDO::PARAM_STRING by default
$query->bindValue(1, $_POST['userName']);
$query->bindValue(2, $_POST['userLast']);
$query->execute();
```

Or if you preffer the other sintax:

```
$query = $dbc->prepare( "INSERT INTO `PdoTest1` (userName,userLast,reqistration_date) 
VALUES (:username, :userLast, NOW())");
# If we leave out the third parameters, it is set to
# PDO::PARAM_STRING by default
$query->bindValue(':username', $_POST['userName']);
$query->bindValue(':userLast', $_POST['userLast']);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: how secure is this method we just worked on vs SQL injection attacks?

Comment: Good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection